# Arduino class to control a RGB led

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-c++

I'm a new arduino user, so I'm learning now...

I want make a new class to control my RGB led...

I already use this led with a method on my code... But I want to generalize the code to put more led without ctrl+c ctrl+v my code.

I create the class:

```cpp
/*
   STATUSLED CLASS DEFINITION
*/
class StatusLED {
  int pinVermelho;
  int pinVerde;
  int pinAzul;

  public:
    StatusLED(int pinRed, int pinGreen, int pinBlue) {
      this->pinVermelho = pinRed;
      this->pinVerde = pinGreen;
      this->pinAzul = pinBlue;
    }

    void RGB(int red, int green, int blue) {
      Serial.print("StatusLED.RGB(");
      Serial.print(red);
      Serial.print(", ");
      Serial.print(green);
      Serial.print(", ");
      Serial.print(blue);
      Serial.println(");");
      digitalWrite(pinVermelho, 255 - red);
      digitalWrite(pinVerde, 255 - green);
      digitalWrite(pinAzul, 255 - blue);
    }

};
```

I initialize that with the pins of my RBG led:

```cpp
#define pinoAzul 9
#define pinoVerde 10
#define pinoVermelho 11

StatusLED led(pinoVermelho, pinoVerde, pinoAzul);
```

And to test it I use:

```cpp
void setup() {
  pinMode(pinoAzul, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(pinoAzul, LOW);
  pinMode(pinoVerde, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(pinoVerde, LOW);
  pinMode(pinoVermelho, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(pinoVermelho, LOW);
}

void loop() {
  led.RGB(255, 0, 0);
  delay(1000);
  led.RGB(0, 255, 0);
  delay(1000);
  led.RGB(0, 0, 255);
  delay(1000);
}
```

The method RGB is called, but my led don't turn on.

If i move the RGB method to outside of my class, this works fine.

Can someone please tell my what I'm doing worng?

Comment: digitalWrite takes HIGH or LOW.  I think you may want to look at analogWrite.

Comment: why do you use integers for values that are in the range of 0-255? why `255- red`? what about your wiring? did you check it is correct? use analogWrite, did you configure the pins as output?

Comment: I use 0 to 255 values because i use PWD ports.
255 - red is because I'm using an anode comum RGB.
I configure pins as output on my setup();

Comment: Can you provide more of your code? for example the setup method etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the configuration of pins as OUTPUT to constructor of my class like that:

```cpp
StatusLED::StatusLED(int pinRed, int pinGreen, int pinBlue) {
  this->pinRed = pinRed;
  pinMode(pinRed, OUTPUT);
  this->pinGreen = pinGreen;
  pinMode(pinGreen, OUTPUT);
  this->pinBlue = pinBlue;
  pinMode(pinBlue, OUTPUT);
  RGB(0, 0, 0);
}
```

This solve the problem.

I also change the method RGB to use `analogWrite` as you tell and now the fade is working well too.

```cpp
void StatusLED::RGB(int redValue, int greenValue, int blueValue) {
  if (redValue > 255) {
    redValue = 255;
  }
  if (greenValue > 255) {
    greenValue = 255;
  }
  if (blueValue > 255) {
    blueValue = 255;
  }
  if (redValue < 0) {
    redValue = 0;
  }
  if (greenValue < 0) {
    greenValue = 0;
  }
  if (blueValue < 0) {
    blueValue = 0;
  }
  analogWrite(pinRed, 255 - redValue);
  analogWrite(pinGreen, 255 - greenValue);
  analogWrite(pinBlue, 255 - blueValue);
}
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to control an RGB LED using PWM (Pulse Width Modulation). To set the pulse on/off ratio on a specific PWM pin, you should use `analogWrite(PWM_out_pin, PWM_out_level);`
Your code is incorrectly using `digitalWrite` which doesn't affect the PWM wave form. It also only takes a `HIGH` or `LOW` value parameter besides pin number.